# Как сделать переключение по адресам для яндекс карты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, yandex-maps-api

недавно видел такой функционал на одном сайте
Такая структура

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-lat='xxxx' data-ling='yyyy'>Адресс №1</div>
  <div class="item" data-lat='xxxx' data-ling='yyyy'>Адресс №2</div>
  <div class="item" data-lat='xxxx' data-ling='yyyy'>Адресс №3</div>
</div>
```

И карта от Яндекс которая подключается по APi
Скажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать что бы при клике по адрессу , центр карты перемещался))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сдвинуть центр карты на выбранные координаты у объекта карты есть метод setCenter. Он описан вот тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setCenter.

Ссылка может выглядеть так:

```
<a href="javascript:myMap.setCenter([55.8, 37.8])">Некая точка в Москве</a>
```

Объект myMap должен быть объявлен, например, так:  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark 
Обратите внимание, что в Я-картах сначала идёт широта, потом долгота, а не наоборот.

Если хочется использовать именно кастомные атрибуты  data-lat и data-ling, можно сделать это с помощью jQuery:

```
$(".item").click(function(e) {
    var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lat'));
    var lon = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-ling'));
    myMap.setCenter([])
})
```

У меня не было возможности запустить этот код, так что он может содержать незначительные ошибки.